# Where are the channel MSP (cred files) stored locally on a Hyperledger Fabric node?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I've read through the Hyperledger Fabric docs and have played around with setting up my own network using some of the examples. However I still am having trouble understanding where the nodes access their channel MSP information.

If I understand correctly, in the default MSP implementation the [Channel MSP is replicated across each node in the channe](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/membership/membership.html#local-and-channel-msps)l. http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/membership/membership.html#local-and-channel-msps However, when I boot up a running network initialized with a channel, while I can see the files that constitute a node's local MSP, I do not see the files that constitute the node's channel MSP. Where are these actually stored in the node and how do they access them during validation?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the docker composer yaml file ,which Up's your docker containers. You will have the volume mappings(physical location) defined for all contianers.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of where the docker-compose file specifies the location of the channel MSP files?
Here's one from the fabric samples.
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/fabric-ca/makeDocker.sh#L209
None of the env variables designate a channel msp dir but it does specify the local MSP information. The volume mappings don't seem to be significant unless the env variables help the peers make sense of mapping required files to where they are in the volumes.

Comment: Sorry if i haven't understood your question rightly!
check out [makeDocker.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/fabric-ca/makeDocker.sh) where LOCALMSPDIR and MSPCONFIGPATH are set in env variables.